Android device internet stops working after turning VPN off
I have problem using internet on my physical Samsung Galaxy Tab 9 after I turn off VPN from device owner app. Bellow I class which I am using for managing VPN. It is not complete but you should get idea how I turn ON and OFF VPN for device.
What I do:
I have a check box in my app to turn ON/OFF VPN. Check box call methods in example bellow.
How it behaves:
After I turn on VPN everything works fine. Problem is that sometimes when I turn it off or I get disconnected, internet stops working. I am not able to load any websites in internet. I have "!" at my Wifi indicator and starting/stopping VPN won't help. Only thing I can do is connect to VPN again and everything starts working but only while I am connected. When I disconnect I am not able to use internet again.
You can check video on this link.
This won't happen always. Right now I was able to reproduce it with fast switching VPN ON/OFF.
What helps:
Only this how I was able fix this issue was rebooting tablet.
This is my VpnService class:
package sk.backbone.bbhub.android.services

import android.app.Activity.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE
import android.app.Activity.VPN_MANAGEMENT_SERVICE
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager
import android.content.Context
import android.net.Ikev2VpnProfile
import android.net.VpnManager
import android.os.Build
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import sk.backbone.bbhub.android.receivers.BBHubAdminReceiver.Companion.adminComponent
import sk.backbone.bbhub.android.repositories.local.ConfigSharedPreferences
import sk.backbone.bbhub.shared.entities.DeviceVpnProfileType
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton


@Singleton
class VpnService @Inject constructor() {
    @Inject @ApplicationContext lateinit var context: Context
    @Inject lateinit var deviceService: dagger.Lazy<DeviceService>
    @Inject lateinit var configSharedPreferences: ConfigSharedPreferences

    val vpnManager by lazy {
        context.getSystemService(VPN_MANAGEMENT_SERVICE) as VpnManager
    }

    val devicePolicyManager by lazy {
        context.getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
    }


    private fun startVpn(){
        stopVpn()

        val deviceSettings = deviceService.get()?.deviceConfigurationFlow?.value?.snapshot?.deviceSetting

        if(deviceSettings?.vpnProfileType == null){
            return
        }

        if(deviceSettings.vpnServerAddress == null){
            return
        }

        if(deviceSettings.vpnIdentity == null){
            return
        }

        val cert = deviceSettings.vpnServerRootCa?.let {
            ByteArrayInputStream(it.toByteArray()).use { inStream ->
                val cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
                cf.generateCertificate(inStream) as X509Certificate
            }
        }

        vpnManager.provisionVpnProfile(
            Ikev2VpnProfile.Builder(deviceSettings.vpnServerAddress!!, deviceSettings.vpnIdentity!!).apply {
                when(deviceSettings.vpnProfileType!!){
                    DeviceVpnProfileType.TYPE_IKEV2_IPSEC_PSK -> {
                        setAuthPsk((deviceSettings.vpnPreSharedKey ?: "").toByteArray())
                    }
                    DeviceVpnProfileType.TYPE_IKEV2_IPSEC_RSA -> {
                        // Todo:
                        // setAuthDigitalSignature()
                    }
                    DeviceVpnProfileType.TYPE_IKEV2_IPSEC_USER_PASS -> {
                        setAuthUsernamePassword(deviceSettings.vpnUser ?: "", deviceSettings.vpnPassword ?: "", cert)
                    }
                }
            }.build()
        )

        devicePolicyManager.setAlwaysOnVpnPackage(context.adminComponent, context.packageName, false)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            vpnManager.startProvisionedVpnProfileSession()
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            vpnManager.startProvisionedVpnProfile()
        }
    }

    private fun stopVpn() {
        devicePolicyManager.setAlwaysOnVpnPackage(context.adminComponent, null, false)
        vpnManager.stopProvisionedVpnProfile()
        vpnManager.deleteProvisionedVpnProfile()
    }
}

Question is what can I do better or what I am doing wrong and how can I prevent bugging myself from internet.
Update

added logcat logs using "vpn" in filter OnStart OnStop.
added logcat logs using "network" in filter OnStop

